# Current Month, Previous Month, Next Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query

```
select *
from RDR1 A
where Year(A.shipdate) = '2021' 
and (
    Month(A.shipdate) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 
    or Month(A.shipdate) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1 
    or Month(A.shipdate) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
```

The above query works fine when they choose the year 2020, But when they choose 2021 it doesn't work. The above query should filter based on the current month. For eg: December 2020 (Current Month), Jan 2021 (next month), November (Previous Month).

How should I modify my query?

Comment: Aside: Since you are not coordinating the year and month you will have problems with the first and last month of each year, e.g. January is month number `1`, subtract `1` and you're looking for month number `0`. `12` + `1` will fare about as well when December rolls around. Dr. Linoff's answer calculates new dates taking both year and month into account. Tip: Also note that his answer uses a _half-open interval_ with comparison `>=` for the lower bound and `<` for the upper bound. If your `shipdate` includes a time, e.g. a `datetime`, it will correctly include the entire last day.

Comment: _works fine when they choose the year 2020_ No, it does not. You are not properly testing your query. That is a very basic developer mistake - just because some rows are returned does not mean it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last month, this month, or next month, I would suggest:

```
where a.shipdate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) and
      a.shipdate < dateadd(month, 2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

This is index-friendly.  If that is not a concern, you can use:

```
where datediff(month, s.shipdate, getdate()) between -1 and 1
```